# Getting "sailpoint.connector.ConnectorException: Build Rule must return a map" error while aggregating the groups from delimited file

Tags: java, beanshell, sailpoint

I ran below buildmap rule:

```java
import sailpoint.object.Schema;
import sailpoint.connector.Connector;
import sailpoint.connector.DelimitedFileConnector;
// Importing the classes which allow us to create permissions
import sailpoint.object.Permission;

if ( schema.getObjectType().compareTo(Connector.TYPE_ACCOUNT) == 0) {
   HashMap map = DelimitedFileConnector.defaultBuildMap(cols, record);
   return map;
} else if ( schema.getObjectType().compareTo(Connector.TYPE_GROUP) == 0) {
   // Calling the Connector to retrieve account attributes as an Hash Map
   HashMap map = DelimitedFileConnector.defaultBuildMap(cols, record);
   String permission = (String)map.get("Permission Rights");
   
   // Here we are using our permission model... Such as: right, write, execute, update on target. 
   if ( permission != null &amp;&amp; permission.contains("-")) {
      // We create an Arraylist bucket to populate all permission objects
      List perms = new ArrayList();
      String [] permissions = permission.split("-");
      for ( int i = 0; permissions.length > i; i ++ ) {
          String target = permissions[i].substring(0, permissions[i].indexOf(":"));
          String permission = permissions[i].substring(permissions[i].indexOf(":"));      
          if ( permission.equals(":YY") ) {
             // For each Permission we have to create a new object. Therefore the multiple new object declaration
             Permission perm = new Permission();
             perm.setRights("update");
             perm.setTarget(target);
             perms.add(perm);
             Permission perm = new Permission();
             perm.setRights("create");
             perm.setTarget(target);
             perms.add(perm);
          } else { 
             Permission perm = new Permission();
             perm.setRights("execute");
             perm.setTarget(target);
             perms.add(perm); 
          }
      }
     // We finished building our permissions and return the ArrayList object which represents a multi valued attribute of permissions
     map.put("directPermissions", perms);
   }
   return map;
}
```

But got the following error:

> Error - Exception during aggregation of Object Type Pam Group
> Permissions on Application Pam Application. Reason:
> java.lang.RuntimeException: sailpoint.connector.ConnectorException:
> Build Rule must return a Map

[image: screenshot]

Can anyone help me here? Please let me know if any modifications need to be made in above code

Comment: What do you mean? please eloborate

Comment: Hi @ScottHunter, I have added the error screenshot please refer

Comment: Image is added can anyone please help.. Any guidance will be very helpful..

Comment: Hi @krishna vangala, I tried by adding below line it didnt work getting the same error...

Answer (score 0):

IdentityIQ buildmap rule always expects a return value of map, even if you dont do anything in the rule and your code doesnt return any map if the conditions fails, that is the reason for your error.
you can just add the following block at the end of the code.

```
return new HashMap();
```